# Can I dynamically change a Label's text in a GridView's header template?

Tags: c#

I am able to find the control and update the text. However, the updated value does not render on the page. Here is the code I used in the `RowDataBound` event.

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
 {
      for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
      {
           Label lblWeekDate = e.Row.FindControl(lblName + i) as Label;

           if (lblWeekDate != null)
           {
                lblWeekDate = e.Row.FindControl(lblName + i) as Label;
                lblWeekDate.Text = burstStartWeek.Day.ToString();

                if (lblWeekDate.Text.Length == 1)
                     lblWeekDate.Text = "00" + lblWeekDate.Text;

                burstStartWeek = burstStartWeek.AddDays(7);
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Did you try calling e.Refresh()?

Comment: Are you using the OnRowDataBound event?

Answer (score 0):

changing the mode to:

```
Content="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}"
```

might help...

find the control on xaml that you want to update and set that binding property.... It might be TwoWay by default but it is worth giving it a try